# adapting a click-to-insert by substituting alternate text

Tags: javascript, html, click

I am trying to adapt this script: [jQuery Example: Inserting text with drag n’ drop](http://skfox.com/2008/11/26/jquery-example-inserting-text-with-drag-n-drop/).

The goal is for my users to click an image thumbnail and have the appropriate markdown image code inserted into the textarea.

I am not familiar with JS, so I am aware that the meat of the script is happening here:

```
$('#ClickWordList li').click(function() {
    $("#txtMessage").insertAtCaret($(this).text());
        return false
    });
```

specifically, the `.text()` bit there, but do not know how to alter the output to suit my needs for a snippet of markdown being inserted rather than just, say, the list text.

Markdown inline image syntax looks like this: `![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)`

I tried changing the list to a div with images and then changing to `.insertAtCaret($(this).src);` but I get "undefined" as the insertion text.

Comment: Did you try `$(this).attr('src')`? <- You'll have to select the images inside your selector then, such as `$('#ClickWordList li img')`, or adapt the `li` selector to `$(this).find('img').attr('src')` if you have images inside the `li`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).src` is undefined because `$(this)` is a `jQuery object`, and jQuery objects don't have a `src` property. Assuming you have an image element in your selector, You can try:

```
$("#txtMessage").insertAtCaret($(this).attr('src'));
```

The [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jQuery method, when given only one parameter, will return the matched element's given attribute's value.

**or**

```
$("#txtMessage").insertAtCaret($(this)[0].src);
```

To get the literal DOM element's `src`.

*Extra explanations (if you need)*
The [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) jQuery method, when given no parameters, will return all text inside of the element referenced by `this`, that is, the event's target, in this case the clicked `li` inside the `#ClickWordList` element.

`.insertAtCaret()` is an extended function of the jQuery object provided by your `drag 'n drop` plugin.

`return false` will do exactly what it says, returning `false` in the `click` event's handler for the selected element, which simply cancels the event and prevents its propagation from bubbling up the DOM further.

Sorry if there are any typos.

Comment: You're welcome =] Just added an extra solution as well, but I'd give preference to the first. (just adding for the completeness :P)